Why won't pip install all dependencies in pytorch/torchserve docker image?
I have the following simple dockerfile inspired from https://supertype.ai/notes/serving-pytorch-w-torchserve/ and I am trying to serve an AI model that uses satellite imagery.
FROM pytorch/torchserve:latest

# # install dependencies
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --user -r requirements.txt 

# copy model archive
COPY model_store /home/model-server/model-store/

# run Torchserve upon running the container
CMD ["torchserve", " --start", " --models my_model=Unet.mar", " --ts-config /home/model-server/config.properties"]


However, building the dockerfile results in the following error:
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/venv/bin/utm-converter'
Check the permissions.

I have tried overriding user permissions with USER root and setting include-system-site-packages = true in pyvenv.cfg but to no avail. The dependencies install perfectly fine in a python:3.9-slim image, but using that image results in build size of over 10GB and torchserve does not work properly.
